# CMake: clean coverage directory before test target

Tags: cmake, clang, code-coverage

I'm working on a C++ project with CMake + clang. I would now like to integrate source-based coverage with my unit tests. When compiling with the right flags, raw coverage data is placed into files according to a pattern given by the `LLVM_PROFILE_FILE` environment variable. Since I'm using catch2 as a test framework I'm thus calling:

```
catch_discover_tests(
  my_test
  PROPERTIES ENVIRONMENT LLVM_PROFILE_FILE=coverage/my_test_%p.profraw
)
```

When running the `test` target, this will place a `.profraw` per test process in the `coverage` directory. I have also added a custom `coverage` target that merges these files into a `.profdata` file:

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT coverage/my_test.profdata
  COMMAND llvm-profdata merge -sparse coverage/*.profraw -o coverage/my_test.profdata
)

add_custom_target(coverage DEPENDS coverage/my_test.profdata)
```

This works well enough. However, if I now run the `test` target again multiple times and forget to clear the `coverage` directory in between, running the `coverage` target will merge data from multiple test runs. That's not what I want so I would like to make sure that the `coverage` directory is always deleted before the tests run. But I'm not sure how to do this, I've tried:

```
add_custom_target(
  clean_coverage_dir
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E rm -rf coverage
)

add_dependencies(test clean_coverage_dir)
```

After `catch_discover_tests` but this results in:

```
Cannot add target-level dependencies to non-existent target "test".
```

What can I do? Should I maybe use a different approach altogether?

Comment: Test fixtures may be worth a look: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/FIXTURES_SETUP.html

Comment: @fabian I haven't heard about that before, I will look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I've found a sort of obvious solution:

```
add_custom_target(
  test_coverage
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E rm -rf coverage &&
          ${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND} --force-new-ctest-process &&
          llvm-profdata merge -sparse coverage/*.profraw -o coverage/my_test.profdata
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}
)
```